# Http, get response from server with rxjs and angular2

Tags: http, angular, rxjs

I don't know what I am doing wrong, I don't get any response from the server to work using Http. I added the project as plunker if someone could have a deeper look.

https://plnkr.co/edit/3HybQY3vcsCImbuFCWrP?p=preview

**post.service.ts**

```
  getPosts(){
   return this._http.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
                    .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
constructor(private _postService: PostService) {
    _postService.getPosts()
               .subscribe(res => console.log(res));
  }
```

Comment: fiddle is getting an error couldnt find system.config.js

Comment: is there any error in the console ?

Comment: There are a lot of issues with the example you posted. Several missing components and file paths don't match up. I would suggest first removing the http and fixing those first. Then update the plunkr

Comment: ops forgot to remove those, but that doesn't really helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wasn't anything wrong, worked when restarted my lite server.

Comment: see my answer below, and plunker too may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You are making **cross-domain request**

You need to add some staff to http request header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

More details: [How to create cross-domain request (Angular 2)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34790051/how-to-create-cross-domain-request-angular-2)

Comment: So their is no other way? Where following a tutorial at udemy and he got it to work using http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com

Answer (score 0):

There are two major mistakes in your code that's your code is not running as expected.

1. you are using `Http` request response but you have not configure `@angular/http` setting in your config file so you have to add this in the file.

   ```
   '@angular/http': {
     main: 'bundles/http.umd.js',
     defaultExtension: 'js'
   },
   ```
2. You are trying to get request over `http` which angular2 won't allow so you have to change your url like

   ```
   http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts
   ```

   to

   ```
   https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts
   ```

here is your working code demo

<kbd>[Working Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/bP4M23WT6DrnT8nU8AlF?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: I see, haven't learn that much yet about the config files ect and in use with plunker, but thanks anyway.