# How to use CORS in angular2

Tags: angular, cors

[image]

In angular2 how to use CORS cross domain, it is necessary to set the response  header at the server, how to set?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the cross domain origin in only server side not in client side. So enable CORS in server side.

And if you are using Web Api for a server call . Enable CORS and Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34790051/how-to-create-cross-domain-request-angular-2/45273215#45273215