# How to setup CORS in angular latest cli version

Tags: angular-cli

What is the right way in production for doing CORS thing in the latest version?

**My function**:

```
 public fetchData() {
    console.log("GET WITH HEADERS");


    return this.http.get('http://192.168.31.73:8080/myjersey/rest/hello/dd').map(
      (response) => response
    )
      .subscribe(
      (data) => console.log(data)
      )
  }

  public authentication(email, password) {
    console.log("POST WITH HEADERS");
    const body = { name: 'Brad' };

    this.http
      .post('http://192.168.31.73:8080/myjersey/rest/hello/dd', {
        email: email,
        password: password

      }, {
        headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
          .set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
          .set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE')
          .set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Custom-Header'),
      })
      .subscribe();


  }
```

below is the exception I am getting:

```
Failed to load http://192.168.31.73:8080/myjersey/rest/hello/dd: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Somehow my Http Get is working but not POST.Please suggest what should i do in this case i have added Access-Control-Allow-Origin in both request and response still getting CORS issue.

PS: I have no knowledge of PHP. I am using Jersey Rest Services with angular.

[image: this is response body from server]
[image: this is response header from server]

Comment: The cors settings should be done on the backend and not on the client(Angular). -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823010/how-to-enable-cors-in-angularjs

Comment: Or -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34790051/how-to-create-cross-domain-request-angular-2

Comment: `headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
          .set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
          .set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE')
          .set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin,Content-Type,Accept'),
      })` makes no sense. You as the client don't get to decide what origins are accepted by the server, only the server can do that. Otherwise what would be the point of the restrictions? Anyone could just say their domai is allowed. These headers are invalid in a request and the server will ignore them.

Answer (score -2):

You need to update the server in order to fix.

Well for development on the local, please setup the `cors` extention in browser.
[How to install the chrome extention](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjhyd.png)

But the important thing is it should be solved on server-side.

Granting JavaScript clients basic access to your resources simply requires adding one HTTP Response Header, namely:

```
 Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
 Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com:8080
```

**At the HTTP Server level...**

**For Apache**

Apache can be configured to expose this header using mod_headers. This is enabled by default in Apache, however you may want to ensure it's enabled in your deployment by running the following command:

```
 a2enmod headers
```

To expose the header, you can add the following line inside , , and  sections, or within an .htaccess file.

```
 <IfModule mod_headers.c>
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
 </IfModule>
```

You can use add rather than set, but be aware that add can add the header multiple times, so it's generally safer to use set.

Finally, you may need to reload Apache to make sure your changes have been applied.

**For nginx**

Merge this into the web.config file at the root of your application / site:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
  </configuration>
```

If you don't have a web.config file already, or don't know what one is, just create a new file called "web.config" containing the snippet above.

**At the Web Application level...**

**In ASP.NET**

Add the the following line to your source pages.

```
 Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

This is compatible with IIS6, IIS7 Classic Mode, and IIS7 Integrated Mode.

**With Python**

```
  print "Content-Type: text/turtle"
  print "Content-Location: mydata.ttl"
  print "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"
  print
```

**In PHP**

Add the following line to your PHP scripts --

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

**In ExpressJS**

In your ExpressJS app on nodejs, do the following with your routes

```
 app.all('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
    next()
  });
```

```
  app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    // Handle the get for this route
  });
```

```
  app.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    // Handle the post for this route
  })
```

etc ...

Hope this article helps!!!

Comment: works for testing, sure, but what about when the site goes live? Every user must use Chrome and download this plugin on every device they use? This is not a scalable solution.

Comment: Yeah, it's true.
The important thing is you can't handle it on frontend side.
If you want to fix in live site, you should fix the issue on backend side.